# Will Apache camel be used between SQL server and Activemq?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel, sql-server-2012-express

**Working of Application Currently:** I have written a trigger for a table in SQL server to trigger a external java application(which is in tomcat server) through http request whenever there is insertion in that table. I used `xp_cmdshell` inside trigger like

```
Exec xp_cmdshell 'sqlps -command "$http=New-Object system.Net.WebClient;
$http.uploadString(\"http://127.0.0.1:8080/MessageProducer\",\"param1=somevalue ^& param2=thriu\")"'
```

The java application is written to take the `queryString` and produce message in `activemq`. Finally I get message in `activemq` whenever there is insertion in `SQL server`.

**Working of Application I want:** SQL server is capable of send message whenever there is update/insert in SQL server, so why should I use java application as intermediate between SQL server and activemq. Is there a way to send message from SQL server to activemq.  While I code for activemq I came across `Apache camel`, will this help for me?.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to use any intermediate software such as your Tomcat thing or Apache Camel if you don't want to. ActiveMQ can receive messages [right out of the box](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) the way you send it today.

It will be something like this (you might want to add authentication if needed):

```
Exec xp_cmdshell 'sqlps -command "$http=New-Object system.Net.WebClient;
$http.uploadString(\"http://localhost:8161/api/message/TEST?type=queue\",\"param1=somevalue ^& param2=thriu\")"'
```

Comment: @peter. I am getting a consumer when i run this piece of code. From the question think the OP wants to populate the activemq queue when something changes in his sql db. can we do this?

Comment: @peter I want to send message from sql server to external application. [check my previous post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593248/message-from-sql-server-to-external-application-activemq). I did post this question that I might get reply to place Apache camel to get message from sql server and produce msg to activemq.

Comment: What's wrong? This URL http://localhost:8161/api/message/TEST?type=queue with a HTTP/POST puts the content of the POST message to the "TEST" queue. Seems to me as the easiest way. An other alternative might be to write a small queue producer in .NET using ActiveMQ NMS and embedd it in the trigger http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179562.aspx

Comment: Even though I'm a Camel fanboy I see no point in adding more components. Camel can not really listen to triggers - just poll some tabel/view and then produce message. You need your trigger in SQL in any case (either to produce message directly or have a poll table populated with rows which Camel can fetch and produce messages from).

Comment: @Petter the alternative way you said "write a small queue producer in .NET using ActiveMQ NMS and embedd it in the trigger" I like, but our application is non .net application. Is there any other way to make our requirement work out?